# Is there any difference between "wobble", "shake" and "tremble" when it comes to the voice?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can I use "shook", "wobbled" and "trembled" interchangeably in the following context? I remember a native speaker once said that "wobbled" didn't work here. But according to many dictionaries, "wobble" can mean the same as "shake" or "tremble".

> My voice shook/wobbled/trembled with emotion when I spoke to him.

Comment: All three are valid and similar, but not exactly equivalent. "Wobbled"  is not common. A voice that wobbles is more likely to indicate inebriation or uncertainty than emotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wobble" is in a different register from "shake" and "tremble". A jelly wobbles. So does a fat man's belly. There's probably a cartoon character named Mr Wobble. It's a funny sound, like [bobble](https://www.hurlinghampolo1875.com/wool-blend-bobble-hat/) and [Pobble](https://thecharmedbookshop.com/listing/987297084/the-pobble-who-has-no-toes-by-edward), and it [often appears in children's storie](https://www.google.com/search?q=wobble&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1irOkn6_zAhUQYcAKHQB3ASsQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1366&bih=655&dpr=1)s. Your sentence doesn't seem to be aimed at children, so either "shook" or "trembled" might be more suitable.

Comment: So what do you think about these definitions of "wobble" from various dictionaries? Wobble: to tremble or shake: her voice wobbled with emotion (Collins English Dictionary); to tremble or quaver: The child's voice wobbled with emotion (American Heritage Dictionary); to show unsteadiness. tremble. quaver: His voice wobbled (WordReference Random House Dictionary).

Comment: Shook or tremble maybe have more connotations of being shaken by an external force, while wobble means shaking because of lack of internal strength. I intuitively feel that wobble is less serious in nature, while shook or trembled are more likely to imply stress or trauma. You would also use wobble for something like vibrato or tremolo. You don't get this sort of context from a dictionary.

Comment: @BeatsMe: The meanings - wobble, tremble, shake, quaver - are indeed similar. It is the _register_ that's different. If we're told, "her/his voice wobbled with emotion" it suggests we are not to take them entirely seriously. Perhaps in the case of the child's voice, "wobbled" is apt, but in the OP's sentence I don't think it is.